# preg_replace_callback() warning when running a CakePHP shell

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am running:
Apache 2
PHP 5.3.3
CentOS

And when I check pcre, I see:

pcretest -C

```
PCRE version 6.6 06-Feb-2006
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  Newline character is LF
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

However, when trying to run a shell, I get the following:

```
Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 4 in /var/CakePHP/cakephp_2.0.5/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 186
```

I have read all of the tickets about PHP version, making sure pcre is up-to-date, and ensuring pcre has unicode support on the cakephp bug list. Any ideas how to resolve this so I can run console commands in CakePHP 2.0.5?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, here is the code on line 185:

```
return preg_replace_callback(
   '/<(?<tag>[a-z0-9-_]+)>(?<text>.*?)<\/(\1)>/ims', array($this, '_replaceTags'), $text
);
```

Also note that this currently works elsewhere (i.e. running on my MacBook Pro)

Comment: Can we see the actual regex that's breaking?  Right now, this is unanswerable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an upgrade to the pcre is required.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple one-line fix for this. Check out the diff at:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/681/files

Comment: confirmed, this fixed it for me. this deserves the check mark.